# how to install mac os x lion on non-mac hardware

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I am a iPhone Developer. I have a dell inspiron 1525 laptop. I need to install mac os x(Lion or snow leopard) on it since buying a mac is too costly. Just for practicing. 
Guys can anyone help me on how to install mac os. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so you probably won't get a good answer here on stackoverflow.  You may have more luck with apple.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.  You're looking to build a "hackintosh", so this may help you: http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=hackintosh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's totally illegal, but nothing is impossible. There are some tricky ways to do it. But you won't get best results or good development environment in it. So, if you want Mac OSX, then buy a Mac. I will not share any tricky ways to install Mac OSX in dell laptop as it is illegal. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: +1 @utsabiem: Thanks for the answer. What do u mean by "won't get best results or good development environment in it". any example?

Comment: You won't get full hardware support as your laptop hardware is not fully compatible with Mac OSX. May be bluetooth/wifi won't work, you may get trouble with ethernet or USB etc. My source of knowledge is google .. so do a bit search and you'll come to know.